# How to configure bind9 in order to point server IP to nic?

Tags: bind, nameserver, ns-record

## Brief Introduction

I bought a domain name `example.ir` from my country domain name provider `nic.ir` and 
a VPS from `examplevps.ir`.
My VPS gave me an static IP and let's imagine it's: `170.120.100.140`
Installed a web server running on localhost `127.0.0.1` and eth0 `170.120.100.140`.
I can connect to my VPS through ssh and do whatever I want and I'm a newbie... my first VPS.

## What have I done?

Actually setup my bind9 like this:

> named.conf.local

```
zone "example.ir" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.example.ir";
};

zone "140.100.120.170.in-addr.arpa" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.170";
};
```

> db.example.ir

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA  example.ir. root.example.ir. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  example.ir.
@   IN  A   170.120.100.140
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
```

> db.170

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA example.ir. root.example.ir. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  example.ir.
170 IN  PTR example.ir.
```

and also never forget to:
`service bind9 restart`

## What Do I Expect?

```
root@examplevps$ nslookup example.ir
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.ir
Address: 170.120.100.140
```

## This is what I get

```
root@examplevps$ nslookup example.ir
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
Server:     4.2.2.4
Address:    4.2.2.4#53

** server can't find example.ir: SERVFAIL
```

## Conclusion

Based on information I provided above it's completely clear what I want...
and I think I must do something like:

```
  +------------------+
  |      My VPS      |
  |  170.120.100.140 |
  +------------------+
           |
  +------------------+
  | ns.examplevps.ir |  bind 170.120.100.140 > example.ir
  +------------------+
           |
  +------------------+
  |      nic.ir      |  bind ns.examplevps.ir > nic.ir
  +------------------+
```

I read many pages online but still can't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow queries from evereywhere. Either add the following to each of the zone statements in `named.conf.local` to individually allow zones to be queried or add it in the `named.conf.options` to allow all zones to be queried:

```
allow-query { any; };
```

I recommend using `dig` to debug:

```
apt-get install dnsutils # for debian/ununtu
dig +trace example.ir
```

Further you need to point your `nic` to your nameserver. This is usually done in the nic's web interface, where you specify glue records for each zone with the nameserver serving the zone in the form of:

```
ns.example.ir -> 170.120.100.140
```

Most likely you will also have to provide 2 nameservers. You can point them to the same IP, although you will probably get a warning message, that not 2 distinct IP addresses are used.

```
ns1.example.ir -> 170.120.100.140
ns2.example.ir -> 170.120.100.140
```

You also need to define the glue records in your dns server's zone:

```
@    IN    SOA  ns1.example.ir. hostmaster.example.ir. (
                                   ...
                                   (
@    IN    NS    ns1
@    IN    NS    ns2
...
ns1  IN    A     170.120.100.140
ns2  IN    A     170.120.100.140
...
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning Glue Records and yes it worked but allow-query { any;} raised an error.

Comment: You're welcome. It should be `allow-query { any; };` with a semicolon after the brackets.